# SQL CONVERT not returning latest results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good morning,

I have a datetime column and when I do a SELECT query and ORDER BY the latest date it's returning results from a few weeks ago, which is correct, but when I CONVERT that datetime to a VARCHAR and ORDER BY this new CONVERTED column, it's a date from last year.

Apologies, it's for SQL-Server, here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP (5) [dbo].[UploadLog].[UploadLogID] 
,[dbo].[UploadLog].[ChangedBy]
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),[dbo].[UploadLog].[LastChanged]) AS UploadDate
,[dbo].[UploadLog].[CompanyID]
FROM [dbo].[UploadLog]
WHERE [dbo].[UploadLog].[ChangedBy] = '5'
ORDER BY [UploadDate] desc
```

I'm not sure why this is happening but would appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Comment: can You show query?

Comment: Please show your query and some sample data.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your query contains ORDER BY after it converts to VARCHAR. Thats why you're getting the date from last year. You should ORDER BY first then CONVERT the result to VARCHAR. You can use inner queries or other ways to do this.

Btw, if you edit your question and add your query, we could help more effectively.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question with the statement, could you please show me how I would ORDER BY before CONVERT?